# jenkins running powershell script that opens a webpage

Tags: jenkins, powershell-3.0

I have a jenkins job that should run a power shell script which opens a webpage, clicks on a button that downloads excel sheet.

This is my PS script.

```
cls
    $global:url="http://www.testURL.com"
    $global:XLSDoc=""
    Function get-ExcelReport {  
    $myDocPath=[environment]::getfolderpath("mydocuments")
    $ie=new-object -com internetexplorer.application 
    "$global:url"
    $ie.navigate($global:url) 
    $ie.visible=$true
    while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}  
    $Link=$ie.Document.getElementByID("saveExcel") | where-object {$_.type -eq "button"}
    $Link.click()
    $global:XLSDoc = Get-ChildItem $myDocPath 
         | Where-Object {$_.name -like        "resyncreport*"} | foreach-object -process       {         $_.FullName } 
    "XLSDOC $global:XLSDoc"
         }
        get-ExcelReport
```

when i run this from powershell console it works, but when i run it as a jenkins job it is not working.

any ideas ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins when running as Windows service runs up against some issues while launching the GUI based applications. That was tripping me when I was trying to launch a WPF application via script. Try to run Jenkins via command line. If it is the same issue then it should work.